# Enable Spring annotations for particular environment

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, development-environment

I have a Spring boot application(Gradle) with main class as:

```
@EnableEurekaClient
public class UserServiceApplication  extends WebMvcConfigurer{
```

What this annotation does is enable this application as Discovery  Service client(Eureka in this case) but I don't want this to be enabled in local environment as I don't want to set registry for my local environment. So the question is, how can I make sure this annotation is used only in non-local environments?

Comment: When run in local environment just comment //@EnableDiscoveryClient. Then discovery will not work

Comment: @AnupamBiswas, it still has eureka client dependency , that keep on throwing exceptions of not found. Any idea how can I disable that? May be add profile based dependencies, is that a thing?

Comment: add `eureka.client.enabled=false` to your `application.properties`. Create a profile for production or your live system to enable it.

Comment: Please see the the linked thread this answers exactly what you are trying.